# Querying a many to many relationship with additional junction table attribute

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three models, **User**, **Unit** & **Rank**

- A **User** can belong to many **Unit**s
- A **Unit** can have many **Users**
- A **User** has a single **Rank** on a **Unit**

I've chosen to model this as a standard many to many relationship with the **Rank** attribute being stored in the **UserUnit** "through" relationship.

The relevant portions of the model definitions are below:

User:

```
User.associate = function(models) {
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Unit, { through: 'UserUnit' });
};
```

Unit:

```
Unit.associate = function(models) {
    models.Unit.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'UserUnit' });
};
```

UserUnit:

```
UserUnit.associate = function(models) {
    models.UserUnit.belongsTo(models.UserRank);
};
```

This creates what I believe to be the correct database schema (though looking at it now, I realise UnitId/UserId/UserRankId can be a compound primary key, rather than using an ID):

```
                                   Table "UserUnits"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 
Default                 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('"UserUnits_id_seq"'::regclass)
 createdAt  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 updatedAt  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 UnitId     | integer                  |           |          | 
 UserId     | integer                  |           |          | 
 UserRankId | integer                  |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "UserUnits_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "UserUnits_UnitId_UserId_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("UnitId", "UserId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "UserUnits_UnitId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("UnitId") REFERENCES "Units"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "UserUnits_UserId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId") REFERENCES "Users"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "UserUnits_UserRankId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("UserRankId") REFERENCES "UserRanks"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
```

So my question is this:

**How can I ask "Show me all a unit's users with their associated rank"** 
(not the ID from **UserUnits** model, the "name" attribute from the **UserRanks** model, therefore traversing the relationship)

I know exactly how I'd do this with SQL, but am struggling to visualise it in Sequelize. If it helps, this is how I'm currently getting all a unit's users:

```
Unit: {
    members(unit, args, { Models }) {
        return Models.User.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: Models.Unit,
                    where: { id: unit.id }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

Any help gratefully received!